How do you create a custom cron job in Magento 2 and ensure it executes only once per cycle?
Here crontab.xml file
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendor_module_cronjob" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\CustomJob" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>

Here CustomJob.php file
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomJob
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Job logic here
        $this->logger->info("Cron job executed.");
    }
}


What are you exactly referring to -->  once per cycle?

it all depends on what you are referring to by "each cycle". With your current code
<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
It's going to run every minute.
I think what you want is more like once per day. In that case what you want is ; it that scenario it will be running once per day at 3 am each day.
<schedule>0 3 * * *</schedule>
0 – Minute (0th minute, or the beginning of the hour)
3 – Hour (3 AM)
* – Day of the month (every day)
* – Month (every month)
* – Day of the week (every day of the week)


As per your code it's running every minute.
To adjust the schedule in crontab.xml, you can modify <schedule>* * * * *</schedule> to suit your timing requirements. The format follows standard cron syntax:
* * * * * command to be executed
| | | | |
| | | | +----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | +------- Month (1 - 12)
| | +--------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| +----------- Hour (0 - 23)
+------------- Minute (0 - 59)

